# Can LVDS on embedded be set to lower resolution?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, xserver, intel-atom

I have an embedded Atom E3825 board where the BIOS can set for LVDS a minimum of 800x480, while my display is a 640x480 one.
Can I set it to the lower resolution anyway? How to?

I tried with `cvt` and `xrandr` but the former can just figure that 800 pixels wide is the *physical* limit, and the latter can't set timings (if I understood the limits).
In fact asking

```
~# cvt 640 480
# 640x480 59.38 Hz (CVT 0.31M3) hsync: 29.69 kHz; pclk: 23.75 MHz
Modeline "640x480_60.00"   23.75  640 664 720 800  480 483 487 500 -hsync +vsync
```

and trying

```
xrandr --newmode "640x480_60.00"   23.75  640 664 720 800  480 483 487 500 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 640x480_60.00
```

what I get is just an unreadable shrunk screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to *fix* things somewhat.
The main issue was in fact with colors, not showing correct, and that wasn't related to resolution. This old model 640x480 pixel panel is expecting to get **18 bits** color and not 24 bits, as the BIOS defaulted to.

So my fix was to set 18 bits color on BIOS and go on with 800x480 pixel, ignoring the additional (invisible) 160 pixels to the right of the screen...